# Im getting error in this line "mne.externals.pymatreader import read_mat" and the error is - No module named 'mne.externals'

Tags: mne-python

Im getting error in this line "mne.externals.pymatreader import read_mat" , and the error is -  No module named 'mne.externals'

I want to know how to remove this error